# OpenXML sdk 2.5 Excel new column issue

Tags: excel, openxml

I have part of code that generates Excel document using OpenXML. 
The problem is to set custom column width. This question is frequently 
discussed herew on SO, but unfortunately nothing helped to me.

So here the code of creating file:

```
SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream
     , SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());
Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
{
     Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.
     GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
     SheetId = 1,
     Name = _sheetName
};
sheets.Append(sheet);
document = spreadsheetDocument;
wbPart = workbookpart
```

After creating I am trying to set custom column width to the first column

```
Worksheet ws = ((WorksheetPart)(wbPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id))).Worksheet;
Columns columns = new Columns();                
Column column = new Column() { Min = (UInt32Value)5U, Max = (UInt32Value)5U,
     Width = 16D, CustomWidth = true };
columns.Append(column);
ws.Append(columns);
ws.Save();
```

Code runs without any exceptions, but result file is broken
Here is the structure opf result sheet xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<x:worksheet xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
-<x:sheetData> 
      -<x:row r="7"> 
         -<x:c r="A7" t="s" s="6">    
              <x:v>11</x:v>   
          </x:c> 
         -<x:c r="B7" t="s" s="6">    
              <x:v>12</x:v>    
          </x:c>  
         -<x:c r="C7" t="s" s="6">    
              <x:v>13</x:v>    
          </x:c>    
     </x:row>    
</x:sheetData>
-<x:cols>    
     <x:col customWidth="1" width="16" max="5" min="5"/>    
</x:cols>    
</x:worksheet>
```

**So the question is, what am I doing wrong ?**

UPD. Problem solved, thanks to [petelids](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3791802/petelids). 
I just added :

```
SheetData sheetData = ws.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
ws.InsertBefore(columns,sheetData);
```

And then, only specify the range here **Min = (UInt32Value)5U, Max = (UInt32Value)5U**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the order of your elements incorrect which leads to a corrupted file message. The [ECMA-376 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) defines the XML for a `Worksheet` as

```
<xsd:complexType name="CT_Worksheet">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="sheetPr" type="CT_SheetPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="dimension" type="CT_SheetDimension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetViews" type="CT_SheetViews" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetFormatPr" type="CT_SheetFormatPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="cols" type="CT_Cols" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetData" type="CT_SheetData" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetCalcPr" type="CT_SheetCalcPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetProtection" type="CT_SheetProtection" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="protectedRanges" type="CT_ProtectedRanges" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="scenarios" type="CT_Scenarios" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="autoFilter" type="CT_AutoFilter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="sortState" type="CT_SortState" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="dataConsolidate" type="CT_DataConsolidate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="customSheetViews" type="CT_CustomSheetViews" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="mergeCells" type="CT_MergeCells" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="phoneticPr" type="CT_PhoneticPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="conditionalFormatting" type="CT_ConditionalFormatting" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element name="dataValidations" type="CT_DataValidations" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="hyperlinks" type="CT_Hyperlinks" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="printOptions" type="CT_PrintOptions" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="pageMargins" type="CT_PageMargins" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="pageSetup" type="CT_PageSetup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="headerFooter" type="CT_HeaderFooter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="rowBreaks" type="CT_PageBreak" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="colBreaks" type="CT_PageBreak" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="customProperties" type="CT_CustomProperties" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="cellWatches" type="CT_CellWatches" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="ignoredErrors" type="CT_IgnoredErrors" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="smartTags" type="CT_SmartTags" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="drawing" type="CT_Drawing" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="drawingHF" type="CT_DrawingHF" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="picture" type="CT_SheetBackgroundPicture" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="oleObjects" type="CT_OleObjects" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="controls" type="CT_Controls" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="webPublishItems" type="CT_WebPublishItems" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="tableParts" type="CT_TableParts" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="extLst" type="CT_ExtensionList" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Notice that it's a `sequence` so the order of the items matters and `cols` comes before `sheetData` (lines 5 and 6).

In your case you need to add the `Columns` directly *before* `SheetData`. There's an [`InsertBefore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc821755(v=office.15).aspx) method on the `Worksheet` which can be used in place of your call to `Append`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @petelids!